# Wordpress add_filter() to add first image to RSS -- causing server error

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, add-filter, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am trying to use this function in **functions.php** to grab the thumbnail of posts and add them to my RSS feed.

```
function featuredtoRSS($content)
{
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'style' => 'float:left; margin:0 15px 15px 0;' ) ) . '' . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

Problem is -- this crashes my server. I get a 500 error. If I comment out the `add-filter` lines there's no error.

Anyone give a hand re what's going on here? I am using Wordpress 3.1.2, Thesis Theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code on my dev site and it works as expected. It may not work due to post-thumbnail support not being enabled. From the codex:

```
To enable Post Thumbnails, the current theme must include add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); in its functions.php file.
```

Source:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: that's interesting, thanks for the comment - I'll look into this and get back with an update